# ffmpeg streaming UDP port is closed

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, nmap, rtsp, ffprobe

I'm trying to use ffmpeg in order to transcode RTSP stream from CCTV to HLS stream so it could be accessed through a web server.

ffmpeg used to stream video from CCTV with following command

```
$ ffmpeg -i "rtsp://cam-1.loc:554?user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0" -hls_time 3 -hls_wrap 10 -f mpegts udp://localhost:6601
ffmpeg version 4.2.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsrt --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] getaddrinfo(cam-1.loc): Name or service not known
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://cam-1.loc:554?user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://localhost:6601':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mp2
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packette=5338.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.12x    
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 3 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 4 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 6 packets
[h264 @ 0x5576c7993c80] concealing 972 DC, 972 AC, 972 MV errors in I frame
rtsp://cam-1.loc:554?user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0=1.11x    
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packette=5298.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.02x    
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 4 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 3 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 4 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5576c7340600] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x5576c779b9c0] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 66 60
[h264 @ 0x5576c779b9c0] error while decoding MB 66 60, bytestream 9825
[h264 @ 0x5576c779b9c0] concealing 943 DC, 943 AC, 943 MV errors in I frame
rtsp://cam-1.loc:554?user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0: corrupt decoded frame in stream 0=1.02x    
frame= 1315 fps= 25 q=31.0 Lsize=   34249kB time=00:00:53.32 bitrate=5261.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.02x    
video:30544kB audio:1042kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.431973%
```

nmap used to check if 6601 port is open

```
$ nmap -Pn localhost -p 6601
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-26 10:47 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6601/tcp closed mstmg-sstp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

However, ffplayer able to play video stream

```
ffplay udp://localhost:6601
ffplay version 4.2.8 Copyright (c) 2003-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsrt --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f1ad854afc0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0. f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 7 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://localhost:6601':0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: N/A, start: 59.288000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RTSP Session
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 160 kb/s
```

VLC cannot play the video stream:

```
vlc udp://localhost:6601
VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari (revision )
[000055769aa81ba0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[00007fec64011e90] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
```

ffprobe output

```
ffprobe udp://localhost:6601
ffprobe version 4.2.8 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsrt --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mpeg2video @ 0x55e1be0910c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 9 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://localhost:6601':
  Duration: N/A, start: 262.760000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RTSP Session
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 160 kb/s
```

Why the video stream is not playing in VLC?

Why nmap do not see that UPD port is open?

Comment: Can you check if the port is listening on the server using netstat ?

Comment: @S.Brottes netstat does not list the 6601 port. Command netstat -an | grep '6601' return nothing.

Comment: @S.Brottes even the port 6601 is not shown with netstat/ss I can play stream from it with ffplayer. It's quite strange situation.

Answer (score 1):

nmap does not scan UDP ports by default, you need to specify this option : **-sU**

> UDP scan is activated with the -sU option. It can be combined with a TCP scan type such as SYN scan (-sS) to check both protocols during the same run.

So your command would be : *nmap -Pn -sU localhost -p 6601*

For the VLC issue, if you are using Debian based system, in a VLC forum post :

> Please note that Debian VLC builds do not support RTSP by Debian policy decision. Use the Flatpak if you need RTSP.

Try to install VLC through FlatPak repository.

Comment: ffmpeg, vlc, ffplayer commands were run on 3 different Linux distributives with the same result.

VLC able to play RTSP directly from CCTV "rtsp://cam-1.loc:554?user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0" but it cannot play stream from FFMPEG. When FFPLAYER and FFPROBE works just fine.

Nmap with -sU determine the port as closed:

Comment: netstat and ss commands shows that port 6601 is not registered at all. Never saw such thing. Thanks for the note about that VLC on Debian branch could have an issue with RTSP.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid remark, but RTSP protocol uses port 554. Could you try to run netstat / ss command on this port ?

Comment: Well, you are right, RTSP uses port 554. I have camera with that 554 port. It works well. Now I use ffmpeg command with input stream from port 554 then do decode/transcode video and output it to port 6601.

Comment: I have tried to use port 554 on local host as output port for ffmpeg. The result exactly the same as for 6601 port. The video stream could be play and probe with ffplay and ffprobe, but port actually closed and cannot be played with any other player.

Comment: I guess the issue in ffmpeg.